# If $f,g\in {\mathscr R[a,b]}$ and $\int^{b}_{a}f=\int^{b}_{a}g,$ then $\exists c \in[a,b]$ such that $f(c)=g(c). $

Tags: real-analysis

Could anyone provide some hint to the problem? Thank you.

Comment: The statement is wrong unless further assumptions are made: Let $a=-1$, $b=1$,  $f(x):=x$ and $g(0)=1$, $g(x)=0$ otherwise.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I have modified my mistaken answer, but credit goes to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Christian Blatter has pointed out, the claim is not true. The function which is the identity over $[-1,1]\setminus\{0\}$ and $1$ at the origin is Riemann integrable, but has zero integral over $[-1,1]$.

Observe, however, that if we ask additionally that $f\geqslant 0$,  $\displaystyle\int_a^b f=0$ implies $f$ must vanish at every point of continuity.